# Don't segue if already the selected UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a UITableView in a Master/Detail application that correctly segues to the detail view controller.  Because of some animation I do on the detail view, I do not want to re-trigger the segue if the user selects the same cell that is already selected--particularly on iPad or iPhone 6 Plus in landscape.

Is it possible to either restrict the segue from firing in this case or program the tableview to not recognize the tap if they tap the currently selected cell?

(I'm programming in Swift but Objective-C answers are just as good.  Either way.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath` in UITableViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return !([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]);
}
```

and Swift version:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath != tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
}
```

Comment: return should be:  return indexPath != tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow without the ().

Comment: @Kent I use Swift 1.2 and there should be a () at the end because it's a method not a property.

Comment: Ah yes.  I'm writing in Swift 2 which leaves it out.  Thanks again!